# How to write dictionary comprehension for the below problem

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Can I do the followign problem using Dict comprehensions

Given this list:
a_list= [ 22, 55, 77, 234, 765, 1234]
Produce a code snippet that produces this output:
a_dict = {2:[22, 55 77], 3:[234, 765], 4:[1234]}
The keys in the dictionary are the length of the digits in a_list.

My solution:

````
    tmp_list = []
    key = len(str(i))
    if key in a_dict:
        tmp_list = a_dict[key]
        tmp_list.append(i)
        a_dict[key] = tmp_list
    else:
        tmp_list.append(i)
        a_dict[key] = tmp_list ```
````

Comment: Probably not a clean way because we'd need either `defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault`. Not everything needs to be a comprehension

Comment: However, there is a much shorter way: ``d = {} ; for n in a_list: d.setdefault(len(str(n)), []).append(n)``

Answer (score 0):

Using groupby, sort and then group by length:

```
a_list = [22, 55, 77, 234, 765, 1234]
print({k: list(map(int, g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(map(str, a_list), key=lambda el: len(str(el))), key=len)})
```

**Output:**

```
{2: [22, 55, 77], 3: [234, 765], 4: [1234]}
```

Comment: But was it worth it? Not everything needs to be a comprehension. This can be achieved in a readable single line if we exclude the dict initialization and the loop itself: `d = {} ; for n in a_list: d.setdefault(len(str(n)), []).append(n)`

Comment: For this task, I'd rather use setdefault, but OP asked whether it is possible to use dict comprehensions.

Comment: Also, with all of these calls to `sorted`, `map`, `list`, `int`, `str` etc . I'd be very interested to see some benchmarking :)

Comment: I know that OP asked for it, but even if the answer is "yes" I'd expect a good answer to clarify the cons/downsides

Comment: Heh, instead of converting to string and backward, it is possible to write a simple algo to count the number of digits. Absolutely sure your versions wins :)

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but it works.

```
{
    key: [i[key] for i in [{len(str(num)): num} for num in a_list] if key in i]
    for key in [len(str(num)) for num in a_list]
}

>>> {2: [22, 55, 77], 3: [234, 765], 4: [1234]}
```

Be warned, this approach is not readable or efficient in terms of looping.

Comment: You forgot one more loop :D

Comment: @DeepSpace lol I had to show some restraint

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict` is going to be more efficient than a comprehension in this case. Also, `math.log10` is more efficient than `len(str(digit))`:

```
res = defaultdict(list)
for digit in digits:
    res[int(log10(digit))+1].append(digit)
```

---

```
{2: [22, 55, 77], 3: [234, 765], 4: [1234]}
```